# is there any way to know the position of my cursor - in TextBox control?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have in my C# (WinForms) program TextBox control

if i have this text in: `abcd efg hijklmnop`

and i stand with my cursor between `c` and `d`  = position 3

or i stand with my cursor between `h` and `i`  = position 10

how to get this position ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [`TextBox.SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart.aspx) that should have the current cursor position.